# Jekyll site returns 404

Tags: jekyll, ratchet

I downloaded the `ratchet` library from here: https://github.com/avinoamr/ratchet/tree/304b16ed61e0c9e2677c6d655ff7e0049910bb7c

.. and I'm trying to build the docs using `Jekyll`:

```
cd /Users/myusername/ratchet-53/docs/
sudo jekyll serve
```

.. it gives me the the server address `http://127.0.0.1:4000/` and no errors, but only the main page loads, all other pages return an error:

```
Not Found

`/getting-started' not found.
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08) at 127.0.0.1:4000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the `_config.yml` file is in `/Users/myusername/ratchet-53/`.

If you do a :

```
cd /Users/myusername/ratchet-53
sudo jekyll serve
```

All will be ok from `http://127.0.0.1:4000/`.